# PHP Laravel how to sort by category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel application and I have now added two tables, an "employees" and "employees_category" table. Both of them have an "order" column so that I can set the order of how the categories and employees will be displayed on the website.

When I add an employee, I can assign them to a category. So far so good, I'm able to display the employees in order they have been set, but not the categories.

This is what I have so far:

My EmployeesController:

```
public function index()
{
    $employees = Employee::all()->groupBy('category');

    return view('app.employee.index', compact('employees'));
}
```

And in my blade view:

```
@foreach ($employees as $category => $workers)
<div class="col text-center mb-6">
    <h2>{{ $category }}</h2>
</div>
<div class="row px-4 px-xl-10">
    @foreach($workers->sortBy('employee_order') as $worker)
      // some content
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

This sorts the employees correctly by order-number but not the categories, how can I achieve that?

Comment: user oderby in query two times

Comment: @st80 did you figured it out ?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you query exactly what you want in your view

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('employees')->get();

    return view('app.employee.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

and in the view : (notice what you want is `as $category => $workers`)

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<div class="col text-center mb-6">
    <h2>{{ $category }}</h2>
</div>
<div class="row px-4 px-xl-10">
    @foreach($category->employees->sortBy('employee_order') as $worker)
      // some content
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

The good thing is you can now paginate on the catogories

Comment: This gives me : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()`

Comment: my bad, it should be `get()` instead of `all()`

Comment: Hmm, something seems wrong `Call to undefined relationship [employees] on model `

Comment: @ST80 declare the relation `employees` in the `Category::class`. i guess it's `hasMany` relation